# Return value from firebase database Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My attempts at retrieving the value of a firebase record are failing.  My JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "-KRPSyO4B48IpBnHBTYg" : {
      "dateCreated" : "",
      "email" : "",
      "provider" : "",
      "userId" : ""
    }
  },
  "products" : {
    "-KUKRafaNurpFhGF4jQa" : {
      "name" : ""

    }
  },
  "total" : 1
}
```

I'm trying to return the value of "total".  Here's the latest attampt:

```
var totals = firebase.database().ref('total').once('value', function(products) {});
    $scope.totalPosts = totals;
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="card" ng-controller="myController">{{totalPosts}}</div>
```

All I'm getting is an empty {}.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries are asynchronous, try this.

```
firebase.database().ref('total').once('value', function(products) {
  $scope.totalPosts = products.val();
});
```

[Read and write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting empty braces..  and this error: "TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures"